# Нужна помощь с двойной версией алгоритма поиска чисел в массиве от 2-х до k

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, простые-числа

Дано целое число k > 2. Напечатать все числа из диапазона [2, 3, ..., k], не являющиеся простыми. Показать несколько примеров программы.

Речь идёт о выборке из заданного диапазона нужных нам элементов, а затем - о создании нового массива. Соответственно, мы можем воспользоваться как минимум двумя возможными вариантами логики решения поставленной задачи:

а) Выбираем нужный нам вариант чисел. Пройдя по массиву, проанализируем каждый из его элементов. Выберем только те варианты чисел, что не будут простыми.

б) Отсеиваем из поля данных элементы, которые нас не интересуют. Определим простые числа и уберём их, всё, что останется - и есть искомый результат.

Удобнее будет работать с простыми числами. Формулирую основной принцип-описание для корректного распознавания простого числа:

```
const Numbers = new Array (2,k);
while (k > 1); 
for (var i = 2; i < k; i++);
(k % i == 0);
console.log"Составное число";}}
```

Пробовала составить варианты а и б полностью. Ни в какую.
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить.

Ещё черновой вариант:

```
const count = [2, k]; // задаю параметры массива
{count.array: id} // ввожу переменную 
const names = ID.map (el => el.id); //назначила формат и имя массива, который хочу получить на выходе
for ID (i = 2; i <= k; i++) 
{if (i/2 == 0) {el.id = false}, // проверяю на простые числа
console log(names.indexOf(el));} //возвращаю
console.log(ID.filter(el => el.id > k)); //вывожу результат
```

Comment: А это точно javaScript?

Comment: Попробуйте вот в [этой выборке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) поискать нужные вам варианты

Comment: Для разделения всех чисел диапазона на простые и составные удобно использовать решето Эратосфена.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно получить все делители числа списком (Python). Если длина списка = 1, то число простое. Тогда его не выводим. В противном случае - выводим.

```
def multiply(number):
    n = 2
    list_multipliers = []
    while number != 1:
        if number % n == 0:
            list_multipliers.append(n)
            number = number / n
        else:
            n += 1
    return list_multipliers
```

На вход ожидается `int`, на выходе отдаётся `list`.

Решение способом А (нужна функция `multiply()`):

```
start = int(input())
end = ''
for k in range(2, start):
    if len(multiply(k)) != 1:
        end = end + str(k)
print(end)
```

Comment: Я тут javaScript не наблюдаю...

Comment: @SwaD, я тоже. Но и в вопросе я не наблюдаю JS, и тем более указания, на каком языке писать.

Comment: Тег в вопросе говорит об обратном... Ну хотите, пишите конечно, никто же не запрещает )

Comment: @SwaD, ладно, ща портирую.

UPD: ща растянулось на завтра.

Comment: @MrSvinia на 8 дней уже :D

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, знаю, знаю. Экзамены навалились. Ботаны для форумов - они и в школах есть XD.

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю этот вариант здесь:

```js
/** @typedef {number[]} NumType */
// Создадим нужные переменные
/** @type {NumType} */
let beginArr = [];
/** @type {NumType} */
const simple = [];
/** @type {NumType} */
const combo = [];
// Создадим массив до k элементов
const k = 100;
for (let i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
  beginArr.push(i)
}

/** @type {NumType} */
const arrSecond = [ ...beginArr ]; // Для второго варианта

function simpleNumber(nums) {
  const start = nums.splice(0, 1)[0];
  nums = nums.filter(item => {
    if(item % start === 0) {
      combo.push(item);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  simple.push(start);
  if (nums.length) simpleNumber(nums)
}
// Первый вариант
simpleNumber(beginArr);

console.log('Простые', simple);
console.log('Составные', combo);
// Второй вариант
console.log('Составные 2', arrSecond.filter(it => !simple.includes(it)));
```